# Is it possible for a function and its inverse to have intersections that are not on $y=x$?

Tags: functions

Define a function $y=f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$. Can the graph of this function and that of $y=f^{-1}(x)$ have intersection(s) that cannot be represented in the form $(k,k)$, where $k$ is a real number? How about other domains?

Comment: Sure. Consider $f(x)=-x$.

Comment: Y=$e^x$ and y=log x have empty intersection

Comment: The graph of $f^{-1}$ is the reflection across the line $y=x$ of the graph of $f$. So if you want them to intersect at the point $(a,b)$, just pick $f$ so that $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$ (and $f$ is invertible).

Comment: Continuing from @Karl ‘s comment, if you are only visualising monotonic functions, that won’t work because: WLOG if $f$ is increasing and $a>b$, then $f(a)=b>a=f(b)$  which is a contradiction. Same goes if $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Is the domain $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2?$ Anyway, $y=\frac1x.$